# 'Object Expected' Javascript error in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

When I run my page on IE8 I got the following error. While it is running fine on Firefox and Chrome.

I used the following line to include js.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="javascript" src="http://localhost/audit.js"></script>
```

Could you tell me where I'm making a mistake? So that that error is coming on IE8 only.

Webpage error details:

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 24 Nov 2010 08:28:06 UTC

Message: Object expected
Line: 72
Char: 188
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/auditng.html

Comment: You need to show `audit.js`

Comment: Open up the debugger on IE8, it will point you to the error if you have it set to break on errors.

Comment: @user380979 There are some query or javascript code were not works in IE.So pls share the audit.js or any other javascript u using on the page.